# Does anybody know what would happen if I changed input shape of pytorch models?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

In this https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html tutorial it clearly states:

> All pre-trained models expect input images normalized in the same way, i.e. mini-batches of 3-channel RGB images of shape (3 x H x W), where H and W are expected to be at least 224. The images have to be loaded in to a range of [0, 1] and then normalized using mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406] and std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225].

Does that mean that for example if I want my model to have input size 128x128 it is or if I calculate mean and std which is unique to my dataset that it is gonna perform worse or won't work at all? I know that with tensorflow if you are loading pretrained models there is a specific argument input_shape which you can set according to your needs just like here:

```
tf.keras.applications.ResNet101(
include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000, **kwargs)
```

I know that I can pass any shape to those (pytorch) pretrained models and it works. What I wanna understand is can I change input shape of those models so that I don't decrease my models training performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each machine learning model should be trained by constant input image shape, the bigger shape the more information that the model can extract but it also needs a heavier model.

A model's parameters will adapt with the datasets it learns on, which means it will perform well with the input shape that it learned. Therefore, to answer your question **"What I wanna understand is can I change input shape of those models so that I don't decrease my models training performance?"**, the answer is no, it will decrease the performance.

**"I know that I can pass any shape to those (pytorch) pretrained models and it works."**

$\Rightarrow$ this happened because Pytorch team replace all Pooling layer with **Adaptive Average Pooling 2d** so you can pass any shape of the image into the model without any bugs.

Comment: Thanks. As a side question, do you why tensorflow allows to have any input shape? I mean if it is pretrained model shouldn't it as well take only the shape which it was pretrained on?

Comment: I don't have much experience with tensorflow, you can check it by load the model, then print the architecture with `model.summary()` if you used Keras. The layer before Dense / Fully connected layer should be [Adaptive pooling](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/AdaptiveAveragePooling1D) which help you to assign the size of the output feature map no matter what is the input shape

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, anyways, thanks for taking time to explain these question.

Answer (score 0):

In all pre-trained models, the input image has to be the same shape; the `transform` object resizes the image when you add it as a parameter to your dataset object

```
transform = T.Compose([T.Resize(256), T.CenterCrop(224), T.ToTensor()])
dataset = datasets.ImageNet(".", split="train", transform=transform)
```

`T.Resize(256)` changes the image shape then `T.CenterCrop(224)` takes a random crop to help with overfitting in the training data.

The `mean` and `std` are applied to each image before they are used as an input to the model. They were determined when the model was trained, I assume they were hyperparamters.